# how to resolve write_csv() function error message

Tags: r, rstudio-cloud

I am working on Rstudio Cloud. `write_csv` will not work and keeps returning this message:

> "Warning: cannot open file 'cloud/project/covid.csv': No such file or directoryError in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
> cannot open the connection

This is the entire code leading up to this error:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

get_wiki_covid19_page <- function(wiki_base_url, parameters) {
  wiki_base_url <<- "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php"
  parameters <<- list(title="Template:COVID-19_testing_by_country")
  response <<- GET(wiki_base_url, query=parameters)
  return(response)
}

get_wiki_covid19_page(wiki_base_url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php", 
                      parameters=list(title="Template:COVID-19_testing_by_country"))
```

```
root_html_node <- read_html(response)
table_node <- html_nodes(root_html_node, "table")
covid_data_table <- html_table(table_node[2])
data_frame <- as.data.frame(covid_data_table)
```

```
preprocess_covid_data_frame <- function(data_frame) {
  shape <- dim(data_frame)
  data_frame <- data_frame[!(data_frame$`Country.or.region`=="World"), ]
  data_frame <- data_frame[1:172, ]
  data_frame["Ref."] <- NULL
  data_frame["Units.b."] <- NULL
  names(data_frame) <- c("country", "date", "tested", "confirmed",
                         "confirmed.tested.ratio", "tested.population.ratio", 
                         "confirmed.population.ratio")
  data_frame$country <- as.factor(data_frame$country)
  data_frame$date <- as.factor(data_frame$date)
  data_frame$tested <- as.numeric(gsub(", ", "", data_frame$tested))
  data_frame$confirmed <- as.numeric(gsub(", ", "", data_frame$confirmed))
  data_frame$'confirmed.tested.ratio' <- 
    as.numeric(gsub(", ", "", data_frame$`confirmed.tested.ratio`))
  data_frame$'tested.population.ratio' <-
    as.numeric(gsub(", ", "", data_frame$`tested.population.ratio`))
  data_frame$'confirmed.population.ratio' <- 
    as.numeric(gsub(", ", "", data_frame$`confirmed.population.ratio`))
  return(data_frame)
}

processed_data_frame <- preprocess_covid_data_frame(data_frame)
```

and finally this is the line that produces the error

```
write.csv(processed_data_frame, file="cloud/project/covid.csv")
```

**the result of getwd() is "cloud/project"**

this does not work on my local Rstudio app either

Comment: try to replace "cloud/orject/covid.csv" by "./covid.csv"

Comment: (1) Perhaps it doesn't matter, but is it `readr::write_csv` or `utils::write.csv`? (2) When writing a file, `No such file or directory` often means the directories leading up to the file do not all exist from the perspective of the _current working directory_. So when you say that `getwd()` returns `"cloud/project"`, that should be clear: don't include `cloud/project/` in the path component of the file you are saving.